# Converting 1D Array to 2D

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to print a 1D Array Given:

```
int[] D1 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
int n = 5;
```

My Expected Output is:

```
    {11,  7,  4,  2,  1},
    {16, 12,  8,  5,  3},
    {20, 17, 13,  9,  6},
    {23, 21, 18, 14, 10},
    {25, 24, 22, 19, 15}
```

This is my method:

```
cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = n-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        a[i][j] = D1[cnt];
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

which results in:

```
    { 5,  4,  3,  2,  1},
    {10,  9,  8,  7,  6},
    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11},
    {20, 19, 18, 17, 16},
    {25, 24, 23, 22, 21}
```

I'm having trouble assigning the correct positions, looking for help to correct this.

Comment: Flap map it to a single array, sort, re-divide it afterwards

Comment: Similar question was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868110/how-to-get-all-sub-arrays-of-specific-length-from-array/48874352#48874352 Maybe it will help you

Comment: This is somewhat [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934673/cant-find-how-to-program-this-number-pattern/42935590#42935590)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog look in diagonal in the expected output... It begins in right, then left, then below, repeat

Comment: the only reason its coming out the way it is because you picked n as 5. There is order to what you really want to do. You should restructure the array so you can just go through it in one pass.

Comment: @Frakcool ah I didn't see that, thank you.

Comment: Looks like the matrix is flipped, so try doing a[j][i] instead of a[i][j]

Comment: @burrito77 that would just make columns go up in ascending order with the bottom row being `1 ,6 , 11, 16, 21`

Comment: sorry, i didn't look at it closely.

Comment: @user9398856 Try looking at this link https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zig-zag_matrix#Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two sets of loops - one dealing with all the values to the top right of the diagonal (inclusive), and the second one the values to the bottom left of the diagonal.
It is tested for sizes 4x4, 5x5 and 6x6.

```
public class SquareMatrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int[] D1 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int[] D1 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
    //int[] D1 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36};
    int n = 5;
    int[][] m = new int[n][n];

    int cnt = 0;
    // The top right part of the matrix (values 1-15 in a 5x5 scenario)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            m[j][n+j-i] = D1[cnt++];
        }
    }
    // The bottom left of the matrix (values 16-25 in a 5x5 scenario)
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
            m[n-j][i-j] = D1[cnt++];
        }
    }
    printMatrix(m);
}

static void printMatrix(int[][] m) {
    for (int i = 0; i<m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<m.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

producing for the 5x5:

```
11  7  4  2  1 
16 12  8  5  3 
20 17 13  9  6 
23 21 18 14 10 
25 24 22 19 15
```

and 6x6

```
16 11  7  4  2  1 
22 17 12  8  5  3 
27 23 18 13  9  6 
31 28 24 19 14 10 
34 32 29 25 20 15 
36 35 33 30 26 21
```